# How to retrieve captcha and save session with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, save, captcha

UPDATE: SOLVED

> Hi all, i've got it, just save cookie
>   to temp file, and resubmit form with
>   curl and set cookies with previous
>   temp file :) thanks all for respond :)

This my working code

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_register);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);    
        $out['result']  = curl_exec($ch); 
        $out['error']   = curl_error($ch);
        $out['info']    = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

And for next curl just use **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE** like this

```
/* fetch captcha url with existed cookie */
            $ch = curl_init($captcha_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
            $out2['result'] = curl_exec($ch);
            $out2['error']  = curl_error($ch);
            $out2['info']   = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Hi all,

i'm create some script to submit content via php curl. first fetch session and captcha, and user must submit captcha to final submit.

the problem is i can't get captcha, i've try with this code and preg_match to get image tag and return it

```
    $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "1");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "1");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
```

But no luck, page i'm trying to submit is http://abadijayaiklan.co.cc/pasang-iklan/.

I hope someone can help me out :)

Thanks and regards

Comment: Isn't the point of a captcha to prevent what you're attempting?

Comment: if you found the solution - just post an answer, that you posted in comments and accept it, so this question will not be shown as unanswered anymore

Comment: Ferri can you please share in core php what will come in place of $this->cookie and $this->useragent and what exactly would be the step for curl as the two curl just got mixed up, i need to know do we need to first fetch the page then the captcha or fetch captcha along with page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the php manual page on `curl_setopt`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` should both specify a filename. You have them set to '1' (which may be valid, but is that what you intended?)

Comment: Hi all, i've got it, just save cookie to temp file, and resubmit form with curl and set cookies with previous temp file :)

thanks all for respond :)