# post data and captcha to a site with php

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, captcha

I am trying to post data to a url from php. I have checked codes like below from this forum.

```
$url = 'http://www.someurl.com';  
$myvars = 'myvar1=' . $myvar1 . '&myvar2=' . $myvar2;  
$ch = curl_init( $url );  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

But my target site has a captcha as well.
How do I load the captcha on my php and submit it with captcha answer?

I had a look at the link. Didn't get the final solution though. [How to retrieve captcha and save session with PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527729/how-to-retrieve-captcha-and-save-session-with-php-curl?rq=1)
also [How to retrieve captcha and save session with PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527729/how-to-retrieve-captcha-and-save-session-with-php-curl?rq=1) and http://hungrycoder.xenexbd.com/general/how-to-submit-a-form-using-php-curl-fsockopen.html

My target site has code like below

```
<form method="post" action="action_form.php" name="frm_sms" id="frm_sms"> < input     type="hidden" name="nav" value="sms" />
```

I don't need to bypass the captcha but I only want to load a neat form and captcha img but no other junk and submit info with captcha answer.

Comment: What you want to do with a `target` site? (only for curiosity)

Comment: to make  my site ad less and data efficient for users

Answer (score 2):

You will have to first fetch the captcha image using cURL and save the contents of any session cookie that it sets, or note the captcha identifier (depends on how their captcha works) and then save a copy of the image to your server.

Then in your form display the copy of the captcha to your visitor.  Add an input field for them enter the captcha solution add their input to your `$myvars` string, and send the cookie or captcha id that was set with the image along with the form post.

That's one way you can forward their captcha on to your user.  Or maybe they have an API you can sign up for.